# django forms - selected option based on the get request url parameter

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form that looks like this - a form that has a drop down select:

```
class ContactUs(forms.Form):

TYPES = (
    ('hi', 'Say Hi'),
    ('restaurant', 'Introducing a Restaurant'),
    ('event', 'An Event is coming up'),
    ('promotion', 'Interesting Promotion'),
)
subject = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPES)
```

I would like to read from `request.GET.get('subject')` so that I can dynamically select the choices

so it would look something like this:

```
subject = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPES, initial=request.GET.get('subject'))
```

Obviously the choices are: hi, restaurant, event or promotion and the url looking something like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/contact?subject=promotion
```

problem is I cannot do the `request.GET.get('subject')`

How can we solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
contact_us = ContactUs(initial={'subject': request.GET.get('subject')})
```

[Django form initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values).